# How to get the excel file path using java code

Tags: java, selenium

String dirPath = fileObj.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();
system.out.println(dirPath);

I tried this way but its returning the Java Project Path that is Workspace path..

Comment: how are you creating the fileObj in the first place?

Comment: @ DhivyaSubramani: Most IDEs change directory to project workspace(or equivalent) before starting applications.

Comment: File fileObj = new File("aoc test.xls"); like this way i am creating Aakash.

Comment: What i am asking is by defaulty its returing the Java Project file path and my requirement is i need the Excel file path.. and the file can be stored anywhere in my system.

Answer (score 1):

`.getParentFile()` is probably returning the parent directory, which depending on the location of your file could be the project directory.  If `fileObj` is an object of type `File`, just try using `fileObj.getAbsolutePath()` instead.

So try this:

```
File fileObj = new File("myFile.xls");
String dirPath = fileObj.getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println(dirPath);
```

This should result in output similar to:

```
C:/[your project directory]/myFile.xls
```

JavaDoc for `getParentFile()`:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile()

Comment: Thank you framauro  for your response and even i am getting the same error.. :(

Comment: Java Path=C:\Documents and Settings\z007981\workspaceSelenium\AOC_CompleteBuild_Copy\20130819_POB$X452SUVP_version.xls;

Comment: Java Project Path=C:\Documents and Settings\z007981\workspaceSelenium\AOC_CompleteBuild_Copy\20130819_POB$X452SUVP_version.xls;    File Path=d:\LocalData\z007981\Desktop\AocTestFiles\20130819_POB$X452SUVP_version.xls;

Comment: In that above post i want to get the File Path.