# How to make my path relative in selenium apache poi while I input my Excel file? and How to write the test result in excel after performing testing

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

```
FileInputStream input=new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Report\\TestCase.xls"));
HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook(input);
HSSFSheet sheet=workbook.getSheet("KeywordFramework");
System.out.println("i am in");
```

How can i make my path a relative path ?
Example (..\..\TestCase.xls)
It should search the file in system and call it , is the requirement

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook(input);
  ExpectedOP=Cellvalue;
    int LastRow = 1;
        for(int i1=1;i1<5;i1++)
        {
        String sr [] =new String [10];
        sr[i1]=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='stepList']/li["+i1+"]")).getText();
        System.out.println("UserID = "+sr[i1]);
        for (int j1=1;j1<sr.length;j1++)
            {
            if(ExpectedOP.equals(j1))
            {
                System.out.println("compare pass");
                String status="PASS";
                Row row1 = sheet.getRow(LastRow);

                Cell cell2 = row1.createCell(18);
                cell2.setCellValue(status);
                System.out.println(status);

                input.close();
                FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File("TestCase.xls"));
                workbook.write(outFile);
            }
            else
            {
            System.err.println("compare fail");
            String status = "FAIL";
            Row row1 = sheet.getRow(LastRow);

            Cell cell2 = row1.createCell(18);
            cell2.setCellValue(status);
            System.out.println(status);

            input.close();
            FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File("TestCase.xls"));
            workbook.write(outFile);
            }
            }
        }
```

This is my code to compare value from website and excel and here am telling IDE to place the pass/fail result in cell number 18 , which i want to make dynamic and also in "i1<5" "5" should be removed and made dynamic which number of cell counts 
Thank you

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226434/how-to-get-the-excel-file-path-using-java-code

Comment: This is not a Selenium problem! This is a pure Java problem finding a file in the system.

Comment: Hi Helping Hands , i went to the link you have referred me to i got the path of the file using the code suggested , but poi considers path as (example : C//123//test.xls) Code suggested there gives path in normal way that is , C/123/test.xls , is there anyway i can fix this ?

Comment: POI can consider path like D:\\data.xls

Comment: yes , you can observe in the code attached to my question above for reference :) , is there anyway i can change "\" in path to "\\" ?

Comment: Can you try like : FileInputStream input=new FileInputStream(new File("TestCase.xls"));   In your code? I think it should work.

Comment: Thank you it is working but ,if i convert my code to a jar file and run it in mac OS based laptops will it work fine ? (Condition :I will keep jar file and Excel file(TestCase.xls) in same folder)

Comment: Helping Hands , can you please help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24604296/null-pointer-exception-in-apache-poi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try like :

```
 FileInputStream input=new FileInputStream(new File("TestCase.xls"));
```

In your code? I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you pass a valid FileInputStream to POI you can use any valid file path you want to open the workbook. So the following code should work fine:

```
FileInputStream input=new FileInputStream(new File("../../TestCase.xls"));
HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook(input);
HSSFSheet sheet=workbook.getSheet("KeywordFramework");
System.out.println("i am in");
```

Comment: An IOException was caught!
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\..\TestCase.xls (The system cannot find the file specified)
This is the error i am getting , where as TeastCase.xls is present in the same folder where the code is

Comment: Please check what your current working directory is. The code above will look for a file relative to this working directory. When running a maven project for example it is not the directory where your source files are but the root directory of the project. To get your working directory you can try: 
File workingDir = new File("");
System.out.println("Working directory is: " + workingDir.getAbsolutePath());